# Generate unique filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I need unique filenames for my files.

```
def filename
    "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.gif"
end
```

This saves a file such as this:

```
ylGP48WxZXOY2OQ_x9dxAA.gif
```

however its respective field in the database to be saved like this:

```
jED48PRNz0asZzwYQXzecw.gif
```

I think what's happening is that Carrierwave is calling the `file_name` function when it's writing the file and when its saving the instance in the database, resulting in urlsafe_base64 being called twice and creating two different strings. It works perfectly when I've hardcoded a name as a test.

So how can stop this? I know it's outrageous to ask, but how can I make Carrierwave use the same randomly generated filename in the database and when writing the file? I seriously think this should be considered a bug.

Comment: when you just want a unique filename, why don't you try to consider `YYYYMMddHHmmss.gif` as your filename..?

Comment: Definitely an option. I just wish carrierwave wouldn't be constantly stepping on my toes... it's good but it could be so much better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one option:

```
  def filename
    random_string
  end   

  protected 

  def random_string
    @string ||= "#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64}.gif"
  end
```

I agree carrierwave could a be a tad more intuitive.

Comment: I'm always troubled by temporary filenames that are generated by random numbers.  Big and random does not mean unique.  It means, fails very infrequently but randomly and inexplicably in production.  Better to use something like the UUID algorithm that combines an arbitrarily unique chunk (like a user name or something) along with a procedurally unique chunk (like system time to the microsecond or a autoincremented number).   For example `Base64.encode64('xyz' + [Time.now.to_f].pack('D*')) + '.tmp'`

Comment: Just an amendment to my prior comment.  Probably want to use `Base64.urlsafe_encode64()` to make sure the output is filename friendly.

Answer (score 3):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

> Tempfile
>
> A utility class for managing temporary files. When you create a
>   Tempfile object, it will create a temporary file with a unique
>   filename. A Tempfile objects behaves just like a File object, and you
>   can perform all the usual file operations on it: reading data, writing
>   data, changing its permissions, etc. So although this class does not
>   explicitly document all instance methods supported by File, you can in
>   fact call any File instance method on a Tempfile object.

```
require 'tempfile'

file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.path      # => A unique filename in the OS's temp directory,
               #    e.g.: "/tmp/foo.24722.0"
               #    This filename contains 'foo' in its basename.
file.write("hello world")
file.rewind
file.read      # => "hello world"
file.close
file.unlink    # deletes the temp file
```

Comment: Tempfile will be automatically deleted. If you need to pass it e.g. to background job (provided single server config), this will not work.

Comment: In Rails 6, I can't use require 'tempfile' in rails console.